# Mock third party classes (Firebase) in Swift

Tags: swift, unit-testing, firebase, mocking, swift3

I'm trying to unit test a class of my own which is calling a method on a third party class:

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.signInAnonymously() { (user, error) in
    //
}
```

I'm using protocol based dependency injection to achieve this:

```
protocol FIRAuthProtocol {
    func signInAnonymously(completion: FIRAuthResultCallback?)
}
extension FIRAuth: FIRAuthProtocol {}

class MyClass {
    private var firAuth: FIRAuthProtocol

    init(firAuth: FIRAuthProtocol) {
        self.firAuth = firAuth
    }

    func signIn() {
        firAuth.signInAnonymously() { (user, error) in
            //
        }
    }
}

class MockFIRAuth: FIRAuthProtocol {
    var signInAnonymouslyCalled = false

    func signInAnonymously(completion: FIRAuthResultCallback? = nil) {
        signInAnonymouslyCalled = true
    }

}

class MyClassSpec: QuickSpec {
    override func spec() {
        describe("MyClass") {
            describe(".signIn()") {
                it("should call signInAnonymously() on firAuth") {
                    let mockFIRAuth = MockFIRAuth()
                    let myClass = MyClass(firAuth: mockFIRAuth)
                    expect(mockFIRAuth.signInAnonymouslyCalled).to(beFalse())
                    myClass.signIn()
                    expect(mockFIRAuth.signInAnonymouslyCalled).to(beTrue())
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So far so good!
Now, I'd like my mockFIRAuth to return an instance of FIRUser.
Here's my issue: I can't create an instance of FIRUser myself.

FYI: `public typealias FIRAuthResultCallback = (FIRUser?, Error?) -> Swift.Void`

If found this great article which explains how to make a method on a third party class return a protocol instead of a type. http://masilotti.com/testing-nsurlsession-input/
Maybe my situation is different than the article's, but here's my shot at this:

I've defined a FIRUserProtocol:

```
protocol FIRUserProtocol {
    var uid: String { get }
}
extension FIRUser: FIRUserProtocol {}
```

I've updated my FIRAuthProtocol to call the completion handler with FIRUserProtocol instead of FIRUser:

```
protocol FIRAuthProtocol {
    func signInAnonymously(completion: ((FIRUserProtocol?, Error?) -> Void)?)
}
```

I've updated my FIRAuth extension to support the modified protocol. My newly defined method calls the default implementation of signInAnonymously:

```
extension FIRAuth: FIRAuthProtocol {
    func signInAnonymously(completion: ((FIRUserProtocol?, Error?) -> Void)? = nil) {
        signInAnonymously(completion: completion)
    }
}
```

Finally, I've updated MockFIRAuth to support the modified protocol:

```
class MockFIRAuth: FIRAuthProtocol {
    var signInAnonymouslyCalled = false
    func signInAnonymously(completion: ((FIRUserProtocol?, Error?) -> Void)? = nil) {
        signInAnonymouslyCalled = true
    }  
}
```

Now, when I run my test everything comes to a crashing halt:

[image: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7fff586a2ff8)]
`Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7fff586a2ff8)`

Please advice!

### Update

After renaming the completion argument label in my FIRAuthProtocol's method everything seems to work as expected:

```
protocol FIRAuthProtocol {
    func signInAnonymously(completionWithProtocol: ((FIRUserProtocol?, Error?) -> Void)?)
}

extension FIRAuth: FIRAuthProtocol {
    func signInAnonymously(completionWithProtocol: ((FIRUserProtocol?, Error?) -> Void)? = nil) {
        signInAnonymously(completion: completionWithProtocol)
    }
}
```

This solves my issue for now, but I'd still like to know why my first attempt was unsuccessful. Does this mean that the two methods with different parameter types in their closures can't be told apart, which was causing my app to crash?

Comment: Don't know if this works, but try subclassing FIRUser and create a custom initializer. This way you could pass the subclass of FIRUser?

Comment: @YannickWinter, Unfortunately not. `Cannot override 'init' which has been marked unavailable`

Comment: Good one ! You have covered 2 nice techniques here 1. Retroactive conformance (forcing Firebase to conform to the protocol), inorder to do Dependency Injection of type Protocol (2) Extending 3rd party and do custom implementation and conforming to the protocol. This way We Own everything and thus making it testable. I had exact situation with another 3rd party while Mocking and Unit Testing. The only difference being at the end of the 3rd party method leaf, it did ultimately take 'String' as input argument and hence I was able to create a method by same name but with arguments  I own. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've finally found an elegant way to solve this.

```
protocol FIRAuthProtocol {
    func signInAnonymously(completion: ((FIRUserProtocol?, Error?) -> Void)?)
}

extension FIRAuth: FIRAuthProtocol {
    func signInAnonymously(completion: ((FIRUserProtocol?, Error?) -> Void)? = nil) {
        let completion = completion as FIRAuthResultCallback?
        signInAnonymously(completion: completion)
    }
}
```

This way, there's no need to alter function names or argument labels.

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer doesn't seem valid anymore as the completion block type has been changed to `AuthDataResultCallback` instead of `AuthResultCallback`.  The former is composed of an `AuthDataResult` (which has a `User` as a property) and an `Error`.  I've posted a question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60146503/mocking-ios-firebase-auth-sign-in-methods which deals with how to mock `AuthDataResult`.