# Mocking iOS Firebase Auth sign-in methods

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, unit-testing, firebase-authentication

This question is somewhat similar to [Mock third party classes (Firebase) in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40561597/mock-third-party-classes-firebase-in-swift) but different enough to warrant a new question, based on the answers to it.

I'm trying to mock the `Auth`/`FIRAuth` method `signIn(withEmail email: String, password: String, completion: AuthDataResultCallback?)` and am running into difficulties with trying to mock the `AuthDataResultCallback` object, mainly because it has a `User` property that I *also* want to mock.  Unfortunately, I'm not able to create my own `User` or `Auth` objects because they've been marked as not having an available initializer in Swift.

I have an object (let's call it `UserAuthenticationRepository`) that's responsible for performing user authentication and database reads.  I'd like to inject a Firebase auth object into it to do these things under the hood, but since I want to test this repository object I'd like to be able to inject a Firebase mock object when I go to unit test it.

What I want to do is something like this (simplified slightly for this question):

```
import FirebaseAuth

protocol FirebaseUserType {
    var uid: String { get }
}

extension User: FirebaseUserType {}

protocol FirebaseAuthDataResultType {
    var user: FirebaseUserType { get }
}

extension AuthDataResult: FirebaseAuthDataResultType {
    var user: FirebaseUserType {
        // This is where I'm running into problems because AuthDataResult expects a User object, 
        // which I also use in the UserAuthenticationRepository signIn(withEmail:) method
    }
}

protocol FirebaseAuthenticationType {
    func signIn(withEmail email: String, password: String, completion: ((FirebaseAuthDataResultType?, Error?) -> Void)?)
}

extension Auth: FirebaseAuthenticationType {
    func signIn(withEmail email: String, password: String, completion: ((FirebaseAuthDataResultType?, Error?) -> Void)?) {
        let completion = completion as AuthDataResultCallback?
        signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: completion)
    }
}

protocol UserAuthenticationType {
    func loginUser(emailAddress: String, password: String) -> Observable<User>
}

class UserAuthenticationRepository: UserAuthenticationType {
    private let authenticationService: FirebaseAuthenticationType
    private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    init(authenticationService: FirebaseAuthenticationType = Auth.auth()) {
        self.authenticationService = authenticationService
    }

    func loginUser(emailAddress: String, password: String) -> Observable<User> {
        return .create { [weak self] observer in
            self?.authenticationService.signIn(withEmail: emailAddress, password: password, completion: { authDataResult, error in
                if let error = error {
                    observer.onError(error)
                } else if let authDataResult = authDataResult {
                    observer.onNext(authDataResult.user)
                }
            })
            return Disposables.create()
        }
    }
```

As noted above, I'm running into problems when I try to extend `AuthDataResult` to conform to my `FirebaseAuthDataResultType` protocol.  Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do? I'd ultimately like to pass back a `uid` string in my Firebase authentication service when testing `UserAuthenticationRepository`.

Answer (score 4):

I was eventually able to find a way to mock the Firebase `Auth` objects necessary for me, but I had to resort to subclassing the Firebase `User` object, adding new properties to it be used during testing (can't create a `User` object directly or mutate its properties), and then creating a struct which conforms to `FirebaseAuthDataResultType` which is initialized with a `MockUser` object during testing.  The protocols and extensions I ended up needing are below:

```
protocol FirebaseAuthDataResultType {
    var user: User { get }
}

extension AuthDataResult: FirebaseAuthDataResultType {}

typealias FirebaseAuthDataResultTypeCallback = (FirebaseAuthDataResultType?, Error?) -> Void

protocol FirebaseAuthenticationType {
    func signIn(withEmail email: String, password: String, completion: FirebaseAuthDataResultTypeCallback?)
    func signOut() throws
    func addStateDidChangeListener(_ listener: @escaping AuthStateDidChangeListenerBlock) -> AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle
    func removeStateDidChangeListener(_ listenerHandle: AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle)
}

extension Auth: FirebaseAuthenticationType {
    func signIn(withEmail email: String, password: String, completion: FirebaseAuthDataResultTypeCallback?) {
        let completion = completion as AuthDataResultCallback?
        signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: completion)
    }
}
```

Below are the mock objects:

```
class MockUser: User {
    let testingUID: String
    let testingEmail: String?
    let testingDisplayName: String?

    init(testingUID: String,
         testingEmail: String? = nil,
         testingDisplayName: String? = nil) {
        self.testingUID = testingUID
        self.testingEmail = testingEmail
        self.testingDisplayName = testingDisplayName
    }
}

struct MockFirebaseAuthDataResult: FirebaseAuthDataResultType {
    var user: User
}
```

An instance of my mock Firebase authentication service with stubs:

```
class MockFirebaseAuthenticationService: FirebaseAuthenticationType {
    typealias AuthDataResultType = (authDataResult: FirebaseAuthDataResultType?, error: Error?)
    var authDataResultFactory: (() -> (AuthDataResultType))?

    func signIn(withEmail email: String, password: String, completion: FirebaseAuthDataResultTypeCallback?) {
      // Mock service logic goes here
    }

    // ...rest of protocol functions
}
```

Usage (using `RxSwift` and `RxTest`):

```
func testLoginUserReturnsUserIfSignInSuccessful() {
    let firebaseAuthService = MockFirebaseAuthenticationService()
    let expectedUID = "aM1RyjpaZcQ4EhaUvDAeCnla3HX2"
    firebaseAuthService.authDataResultFactory = {
        let user = MockUser(testingUID: expectedUID)
        let authDataResult = MockFirebaseAuthDataResult(user: user)
        return (authDataResult, nil)
    }

    let sut = UserSessionRepository(authenticationService: firebaseAuthService)
    let userObserver = testScheduler.createObserver(User.self)

    sut.loginUser(emailAddress: "john@gmail.com", password: "123456")
       .bind(to: userObserver)
       .disposed(by: disposeBag)

    testScheduler.start()

    let user = userObserver.events[0].value.element as? MockUser

    // Assert MockUser properties, events, etc.
}
```

If anyone has any better ideas of how this can be accomplished, please let me know!

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution is no longer valid  The Firebase team decided to hide the initializer of the User class and many other entities too so the subclass you made (class MockUser) cannot be made.

Answer (score 0):

Currently User class doesn't have a public initializer which means we can't create the MockUser like Evan R's answer. Possible solution:

```
import Firebase

public protocol RemoteUserType {
    func fetchIdToken() async throws -> String
}

extension Firebase.User: RemoteUserType {
    public func fetchIdToken() async throws -> String {
        try await getIDToken()
    }
}

public protocol RemoteAuthDataResultType {
    var underlyingUser: RemoteUserType { get }
}

extension AuthDataResult: RemoteAuthDataResultType {
    public var underlyingUser: RemoteUserType {
        return self.user
    }
}

public protocol RemoteAuthProtocol {
    var underlyingUser: RemoteUserType? { get }

    func signIn(with customToken: String) async throws -> RemoteAuthDataResultType
    func signOut() throws
}

extension Auth: RemoteAuthProtocol {
    public var underlyingUser: RemoteUserType? {
        return currentUser
    }

    public func signIn(with customToken: String) async throws -> RemoteAuthDataResultType {
        try await signIn(withCustomToken: customToken)
    }
}
```